# How many permutations of $\{1,2,.....n\}$ derange the odd numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many permutations of $\{1,2, \dots , n\}$ derange the odd numbers?
I have the answer in my text book but I don't know how they got it.

Answer (score 4):

In other words, if $\pi$ is the permutation you want $\pi(n) \ne n$ for all odd $n$.
You can do this using inclusion-exclusion.  For any subset $A \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots n\}$, let $f(A)$ be the number of permutations $\pi$ such that $\pi(n) = n$ for $n \in A$ (and possibly others).  Obviously $f(A) = (n - |A|)!$.  Let $B$ be any subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  Then inclusion-exclusion says that
the number of permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots n\}$ with at least one fixed point in $B$ is
the sum of $(-1)^{|A|-1} f(A)$ over all subsets $A$ of $B$, that is, 
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{|B|} (-1)^{k-1} (n-k)! {|B| \choose k}$.  Subtract this from $n!$ to get the number of permutations with no fixed point in $B$.

See also https://oeis.org/A161131